# Store query result on an array

Tags: database

This is a simple query

```
$sql = db_select('node','n');
$sql->fields('n', array('uid','title'));
$s = $sql->execute();
```

I need to check the uid of all records :

```
if('n.uid' !=1 ) { do some stuff}
```

Should I store query result into an array before the if condition ? If yes how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can replace $sql with $result.

```
<?php
// Retrieve all records into an indexed array of stdClass objects.
$result->fetchAll();

// Retrieve all records into an associative array keyed by the field in the result specified.
$result->fetchAllAssoc($field);

// Retrieve a 2-column result set as an associative array of field 0 => field 1.
$result->fetchAllKeyed();
// You can also specify which two fields to use by specifying the column numbers for each field
$result->fetchAllKeyed(0,2); // would be field 0 => field 2
$result->fetchAllKeyed(1,0); // would be field 1 => field 0
// If you need an array where keys and values contain the same field (e.g. for creating a 'checkboxes' form element), the following is a perfectly valid method:
$result->fetchAllKeyed(0,0); // would be field 0 => field 0, e.g. [article] => [article]

// Retrieve a 1-column result set as one single array.
$result->fetchCol();
// Column number can be specified otherwise defaults to first column
$result->fetchCol($column_index);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, yea I've tested fetchAll() but looks like something wrong

Comment: Try this $result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node}"); and then use this $record = $result->fetchAll(); and var_dump($record); It will give your all results in array.

Comment: So now i can make if ('n.uid' != 1) ect ?

Comment: Yes sure when there is everything is available then its easy to put conditions.